# Is it possible to invert the onmousehover behaviour in a browser?

Tags: browser, javascript, web

Is it possible to modify in some way (by adding stylesheets, injecting JS, or whatever) the behaviour of a browser so that in a web page fully loaded it inverts its processing regarding onmousehover image elements, i.e. it shows the 'onhover' image when the mouse is NOT hovering on the element, and viceversa?

The idea being to build a temporary "toggle" to display all hovered images in a page without mouse interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could write a stylesheet that styles all the elements the opposite way. It might even be possible to write a script that could read the stylesheet and automatically write and apply a stylesheet with inverse behavior. This would be a fairly complex task.

If you're only looking to see the hover state of a few elements simultaneously, developer tools can help. In chromium based browsers, you can lock the `:hover` state on for as many elements as you like. I don't think there is a way to script this such that every element on the page has `:hover` styles applied automatically.